# Find and return first string which contains char (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, find, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a function which loops through a list of strings that looks like this:

```
["     |     ","     #     ","     *     ","     |     ","     #     "]
```

I am trying to find and return the first element that contains either `'|', '#', or '*'`, depending on the users choice.

I came up with this solution:

```
test :: Char -> [String] -> Maybe Char
test c (x:xs) = find (== c) $ concatMap (filter (/=' ')) (reverse xs)
```

And I get this output:

```
ghci> test '*' ["     |     ","     #     ","     *     ","     |     ","     #     "]
Just '*'
```

Which finds the element, but I want it to return the element without altering it (removing the spaces). How can I do this without filtering out the spaces?

This is the output I want:

```
ghci> test '*' ["     |     ","     #     ","     *     ","     |     ","     #     "]
"     *     "
```

Comment: what is the type of your desired output value?

Comment: I want the output to be a String-type

Comment: yes, I know, it was a guiding question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged your question with [list-comprehension](/questions/tagged/list-comprehension),

```
test :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> Maybe [a]
test c xs = listToMaybe [s | s <- xs, elem c s]
```

should do the job.

```
> test '*' ["     |     ","     #     ","     *     ","     |     ","     #     "]
Just "     *     "

> test '-' ["     |     ","     #     ","     *     ","     |     ","     #     "]
Nothing

> :i listToMaybe
listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a   -- Defined in `Data.Maybe'
```